# Как ставить вопросительный знак после паузы с использованием многоточия?

Tags: пунктуация, многоточие

С помощью многоточия можно показать сомнения персонажа и паузу, которая **не** прерывает предложение:

> Я испытывал страх и... радость?..

Вопросительный знак усиливает неуверенность персонажа, потому что он сам до конца не понимает, какое чувство испытывает. Конечно, можно заменить многоточие словом "кажется" и иначе построить предложение, но эффект будет другой.

Как правильно оформить предложение? Ставить ли две точки после вопросительного знака, если мы показываем сомнение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Дополнение-разъяснение** (после комментариев)

• *Я испытывал страх и... радость?..*

При такой пунктуации вопросительный знак, считаю, относится и к страху, и к радости, так как однородные члены, пусть с запинкой, соединены союзом "и".

*— Разве мальчик, в Останкине летом танцевавший на дачных балах, это я, тот, кто каждым ответом желторотым внушает поэтам отвращение, злобу и страх?..* (В. Д. Алейников. Тадзимас).

• Если же персонаж "сам до конца не понимает, какое чувство испытывает" (одно утверждает, а в другом сомневается), то лучше утвердительные и вопросительные части разделить.

*Я испытывал страх... Или радость?..*

• Просто к сведению: комплекс *вопросительный знак + многоточие* используется в литературе уже давно. Вот пример из позапрошлого века (А. И. Куприн. Одиночество (1898)):

> — Когда же ты был там? Ты мне ничего о них не рассказывал... Что они за люди?
> — Люди?.. Как тебе сказать?.. Ни дурные, ни хорошие... Веселые люди...

Answer (score 1):

*Я испытывал страх и... радость?..*
Считаю, что такое оформление вполне возможно, оно никак не противоречит пунктуационным правилам (сочетание вопросительного знака и многоточия, правда, встречается нечасто).

Олег Костман. Сильнее времени:

> — ...На два часа хватит энергии моего изолирующего поля — вот что это значило.
> — И... что будет... потом?.. — Язык у меня вдруг стал деревянным.
> — Ничего. Пустота.
> — И... вы...

Михаил Булгаков. Собачье сердце:

> — Погоди-ка, не вертись, фить... да не вертись, дурачок. Гм... Это не парши... да стой ты, черт... гм... А-а! Это ожог. Какой же негодяй тебя обварил? А? Да стой ты смирно!
> <...>
> — Позвольте узнать, по чему я вас пропишу? По этой скатерти или по своему паспорту? Ведь нужно все-таки считаться с положением! Не забывайте, что вы... э... гм... вы ведь, так сказать, неожиданно появившееся существо, лабораторное. – Филипп Филиппович говорил все менее уверенно.
> <...>
> — Я отравлюсь, – плакала барышня, — в столовке солонина каждый день... и угрожает, говорит, что он красный командир... со мною, говорит, будешь жить в роскошной квартире... каждый день ананасы... психика у меня добрая, говорит, я только котов ненавижу... Он у меня кольцо на память взял...

Comment: Спасибо. Меня лишь смущает, что изначально предложение начинается с утверждения, а заканчивается вопросом. У вас немного другие примеры.

Comment: Вы пишете, "что он сам до конца не понимает, **какое** чувство испытывает". Тогда можно считать, что знак вопроса относится ко всему предложению (то есть и к страху, и к радости — они ведь объединены союзом "и"). Если же первую часть считать утвердительной, то оформление, думаю, может быть таким: *Я испытывал страх... Или радость?..*

Comment: Спасибо за второй пример! Думаю, это действительно верный вариант. Дополните, пожалуйста, этим примером ответ - я сейчас отмечу его, как верный.